# HOW TO EXTRACT LIST 1 FROM LIST2 in Bash/Unix?

Tags: regex, bash, list, unix, compare

I have two list. I just need to extract the rows that have the first list row elements from the second list. Looking for the right syntax to read one list and then the other and extract list one from 2 based on regex. Looking for exact text match. I would like the output to include the whole row from List2 as well. Thanks.

List 1 in a text file:

```
ABC
EFG
HIJ
KLM
```

List 2 in another text file:

```
TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
DDDD;LLLLL
PPPPPPPPP:RRRRRRRRRRadjkfjadl;fireuqwoepiruqwepiormvndfkgjs;
hflahflakjdfhalksdfhfjaoeirfjaklf;sdfgsfgs
```

Desired output..the text in list 1 that was found ..space and then the row that was found in list 2.:

```
EFG TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
HIJ DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
ABC GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep -f`

```
grep -f list1 list2
```

> `man grep`
>
> > `-f file, --file=file`
> >
> > > Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  Empty pattern lines match every input line.  Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If file is empty, nothing is matched.

---

Edit: Example of `grep -f` in action

```
$ cat list1
ABC
EFG
HIJ
KLM

$ cat list2
TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
DDDD;LLLLL
PPPPPPPPP:RRRRRRRRRRadjkfjadl;fireuqwoepiruqwepiormvndfkgjs;
hflahflakjdfhalksdfhfjaoeirfjaklf;sdfgsfgs

$ grep -f list1 list2
TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -F -f list1.txt list2.txt
```

assuming that each line is an exact match for what you are looking for.  Otherwise, maybe:

```
for f in $(<list1.txt) ; do
    grep -E "\\<$f\\>" list2.txt | sed "s/^/$f /"
done | sort -u
```

assuming you want word matches.  Fiddle it to suit your precise needs.

(Edited to remove duplicate results in the loop.)

Works for me:

```
$ head -n 400 list? ; echo ;grep -F -f list1 list2
==> list1 <==
ABC
EFG
HIJ
KLM

==> list2 <==
TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
DDDD;LLLLL
PPPPPPPPP:RRRRRRRRRRadjkfjadl;fireuqwoepiruqwepiormvndfkgjs;
hflahflakjdfhalksdfhfjaoeirfjaklf;sdfgsfgs

TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG
DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP
GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA
ABC;HHHHH;LLLL
```

Comment: yes it does work. Thanks. How can i get the list1 annotated to list2 in the output. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: define "annotated to list2"?  If you mean which key was found in each line, then just use an iterated "grep -F $f file2" loop -- for f in $(<file1) ; do .....

Comment: in the question i have a section for desired output. So something like that..example of one row..EFG TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't usually do full polish on my answers simply because it takes a lot of time.  The only way you do that is in a loop a la:  printf "\n$f:\t%s\n" $f "$(grep -F $f list2)" -- I leave the details to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following shell script works:

```
 for i in $(cat list1.txt );do y=`grep $i list2.txt`;  z=$(echo $?);  if [ $z -eq 0 ]; 
 then 
 for z in $y;do echo $i $z; done ; fi; done;
```

Output:

ABC GSFDHGJH;FHAJDJFKASLJK;ABC;ASDKFHJASKABC;FA;LKDJA

ABC ABC;HHHHH;LLLL

EFG TTTT;KKKKKKK;OOOOO;EFG

HIJ DALFJKHD;HIJ;PPP